# BeanPostProcessor not being called in spring mvc web app

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc 3.0 web application and am trying to implement a generic solution for my initBinder methods. Rather than speciyfying the same initBinder code in all my contorllers for my date picker I am trying to do this (I do not have @Controller advice to help me in this version of spring)

```
@Component
public class MyPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
            WebBindingInitializer wbi = ((RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean).getWebBindingInitializer();
            if (wbi == null) {
                wbi = new ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
                ((RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean).setWebBindingInitializer(wbi);
            }

            if (wbi instanceof ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) {
                ((ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer) wbi).setPropertyEditorRegistrar(new MyPropertyEditorRegistrar());
            }

        }
        return bean;
    }


public class MyPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    @Value("#{appProperties['date.format']}")
    public String dateFormat = null;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar#registerCustomEditors(org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry)
     */
     public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            df.setLenient(false);
            registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));
     }
}
```

But my BeanPostProcessor doesn't seem to be getting called. Can someone help me understand how and when the BeanPostProcessor gets called?

p.s. I am using mvc:annotationdriven

thanks

Comment: *doesn't **seem** to be getting called* - Is it called or not? Set a breakpoint and verify.

Comment: Definitely not being called. I tried break pointing. Do I need to add n e thing to web.xml to tell spring about this class?

Comment: No not at all. I think your class might not be added to the application context. Check your component scan paths.

Comment: What specific version of Spring are you using?  We are using 3.0.6 and it has @Controller.

Comment: Bart... your feedback has struck something with me. It was my paths. i put the class in the wrong package. What a silly error. Sorry guys. Thanks for your help. I'll verify tomorrow that it works when I put the class in a path with the scan is happening.